# CSS (progid:dximagetransform.microsoft) not working after upgrading to SharePoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint

We are in process of upgrading from SP2010 to SP2013.

There is a webpart with the foll. code:-

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20px; FONT-SIZE: 14px;FONT-FAMILY: Calibri;TEXT-ALIGN: center;color:#ffffff;TEXT-ALIGN: center;filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#04a2a4", endColorstr="#cdfefe",GradientType=0 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#000000", endColorstr="#000000",GradientType=0 ); ">hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This renders as follows in SP2010:-
[image: SP2010 render]

Whereas in SP2013 it renders as follows:-
[image: SP2013 render]

**UPDATE**

I did an F12 in IE and here are the results:

In SP2013 where it does not render, I do a F12 and see the foll.:-

```
<td style="height: 20px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px;" "="" );="" ),="" ,gradienttype="0" endcolorstr="#cdfefe" #04a2a4",="" ,="" startcolorstr="#000000" progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(="">
```

Here is the rendered style on F12:-[image]

As you can see, **the progid tag is missing when rendered**!

In SP2010 where it renders well, I do a F12 and see the foll.:-

```
<td style="height: 20px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=;" ?="" );="" ),="" ,GradientType="0" endColorstr="#cdfefe" #04a2a4?,="" ,="" startColorstr="#000000" progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(="">
```

Here is the rendered style on F12:-[image]

As you can see, the progid tag in inline style appears in this case.

Any idea as to what is causing issue for SP2013? It works perfectly when the SP2013 site is opened in IE8! Thats shocking...

Comment: Very interesting. I am currently working on a project and I noticed that linear-gradient(to bottom, #hexcolor 0%, #hexcolor 100%); now works in IE 10 & 11. Also, there is a SharePoint StackExchange. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes I have put question in SharePoint StackExchange as well.. I am using IE10 and both sites are tested via IE 10 and results are pasted above

Comment: I have no idea why it would not work. Have you tried,  linear-gradient(to bottom, #hexcolor 0%, #hexcolor 100%); ? Also, have you tried the progid tag in a CSS tag instead of inline style?

Comment: I am surprised as progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient tag doesnot get rendered in the html!

Comment: I agree, that is very weird. Now, I want to start my SP 2013 environment and try it, haha.

Comment: Actually, this might be why, on the next line add this, filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=true);

Comment: The SP2013 things works perfectly when site is opened in IE8 but not IE10 and IE11

Comment: gradient enabled=true does not make any diffference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this should resolve your Problem.

```
.test {

background: url(fundraiser.jpg) no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3b68 0%, #0029d3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url(fundraiser.jpg) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3b68), color-stop(100%,#0029d3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: url(fundraiser.jpg)no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3b68 0%,#0029d3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: url(fundraiser.jpg) no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3b68 0%,#0029d3 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: url(fundraiser.jpg) no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3b68 0%,#0029d3 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3b68', endColorstr='#0029d3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: url(fundraiser.jpg) no-repeat, linear-gradient(top, #ff3b68 0%,#0029d3 100%); /* W3C */
 }
```